# how to transform string to an array, tokenizing by comma android kotlin

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, kotlin

I am having some trouble with formatting the results from A Room database. The results come out as one big, long, unbroken word, like this `"texta,textb,textc"` when I need them to be a string array, like this `"texta","textb","textc"` So my question in layman's terms is how do I break up the query result so that it works with my API.

here is how I implement database function and retrieve the data:

```
        mUserViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewModel::class.java)
        mUserViewModel.readSomeData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { user ->
        val abc = user
```

I then parse it to the function where the data is `POST`ed to my API, this is how I ready it for export.

```
        val jArray = JsonArray()
        val element = JsonPrimitive(abc)
        jArray.add(element)

//        val element = JsonPrimitive("""texta","textb","textc""")//this works
        //above is what I was using to test the API when I still putting together the database.
```

I have tried a few things to try achieve the desired results:

the first was this:

```
val abc = user.split(",").toTypedArray().toString()
```

this turned the string into this `["[Ljava.lang.String;@e5daa3e"]`

the second was this:

```
    val abc: String = user.toCharArray().map { it.toString() }.toString()
```

this made it so that each letter in the was broken up like this

`["[t, e, x, t, a, ,, t, e, x, t, b, ,, t, e, x, t, c]"]`

If anyone could tell me how to make text that I send to the API look like this `"texta","textb","textc"` I would be very appreciative.

if it helps the strings will always be 10 characters long.

thank you for your time.

Comment: Why do you need to call toString() method in val abc = user.split(",").toTypedArray().toString()?

Comment: because I get a type mismatch otherwise,`JsonPrimitive` wants a String. also I still get `[Ljava.lang.String;@b0e4f60` if I just print it with out .tostring()

Comment: I don't code in kotlin, but I think u create another string, and then use a for loop to check each char in string, if that char == ",", you add the string to array, and set the string to empty, and on else you append char to the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways you can achieve this would be to use the Gson library to serialize the objects, here is an example:

```
val string = "texta,textb,textc"
val typedArray = string.split(",").toTypedArray()
val gson = Gson()
println(gson.toJson(typedArray ))
```

The output should look like this: `["texta","textb","textc"]`

You can find more info in the following link https://github.com/google/gson